# VS 2010 not opening css files in css editor

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010

I have no idea how to fix this.

VS keeps opening css file in some text editing mode, see the picture below.

[image]

I have already tried to set it manually to open using css editor, right-click on css file and select "Open with..."

[image]

When I click OK here, it opens my css file in CSS source editor fine, 
but every next time it opens again in that text mode, like it completely ignores that it has to open it using css editor :(

Of course I installed and reinstalled Web Standards Update a thousand times.

Nothing helps.

The damn thing keeps opening them in that ugly text mode :(

Comment: This is a question that would probably get answered quicker on superuser. http://superuser.com/ It's another stackexchange website.

Comment: That looks like the web browser view.  No clue why that would happen.

Comment: Is there any strange encoding on the file ? Could the file be corrupt ? What happens when you create a new css file from scratch in VS ?

Comment: @grimmus, thank you so much! I should have tried that first. Created a new css file and it worked no problem!! Copied content from bad css file, everything is perfect :) Not sure what the problem is, encoding is identical, UTF-8, looks like the file itself became corrupted (though it opens fine in any other text editor).

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. Have you tried looking under the view menu? It's been a while since I've used it, but I remember different views being under the view menu bar.

If that doesn't work then I'd always try creating a new .css file and copy and pasting all the information; after you copy and paste, overwrite the pre-existing corrupt file.